Cannot play a canvas app after importing it to Another Environment/Another Tenant (using Azure DevOps PP Build Tools)
I have a simple canvas app (contains some screens and connector to mssql db) and I am doing a PowerApp solution export/import from Tenant A/Environment A to Tenant B/Environment B using Azure DevOps pipelines.
But after import, I cannot play the app. I'm getting this weird error:

It's weird because I can go into the editor and edit it, but I can't open it.
Even if I import solution into the same tenant but into a different environment, the problem is the same.
Has anyone encountered this and how can it be solved?

When you use Azure DevOps to import the solution, are there any error messages show in the pipeline? Can you try to manually export/import the solution, will it work as expected?

@KevinLu-MSFT The pipeline does not return errors, the import is successful.

Can you check if the owner of the canvas app is your account or service account?

@KevinLu-MSFT I found what the problem was, I needed to share access to myself.
This sounds strange, but after deployment, this application was essentially not available for anyone to run, but after sharing, everything worked.  Thanks for responses.

I found what the problem was, I needed to share access to myself. This sounds strange, but after deployment, this application was essentially not available for anyone to run, but after sharing, everything worked. Thanks for responses.
